# Make a Client-Side Custom Events in ASP.NET Web-User Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-user-controls

I'm developing an `Web-user control` with a `Text-box`.
Now i need to call `Text-box's` Client event from my `aspx page`.
Can any one tell me how can i create client side custom events.

### Edit-1

I need to create custom client side events in my user control.
So that i can use this event for invocation of any `java-script`function from `.aspx` page where i used my custom control.

### Edit-2

### My Control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl2" ClientIDMode="Predictable" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxControl" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="GridViewCSSThemes/YahooGridView.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumber(evt, id) {
        var a = document.getElementById(id).value;
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (a.indexOf(".") >= 0
        && charCode == 190) {
            return false;
        }
        else
            if (charCode != 46 && charCode != 37 && charCode != 39 && charCode != 34 && charCode != 190 && charCode != 110 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                if (charCode < 96 || charCode > 105) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }

    function formateValue(id) {
        var a = document.getElementById(id).value;
        var f = a.split(".");
        if (f.length > 2) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = f[0] + "." + f[1];
        }
        a = document.getElementById(id).value;
        if (a.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = a.substr(0, a.indexOf(".") + 1) + a.substr(a.indexOf(".") + 1, 4);
        }
        else if (a.length > 7) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = a.substr(0, 7) + "." + a.substr(7, a.length);
        }
        document.getElementById(id).title = "Input value: " + document.getElementById(id).value;
        document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_Value.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    function test(id) {
        alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
    }
</script>
<div style="position:relative;border:none;" id="BssWebMasked">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden_Value" Value="" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="tb10" Width="90" ID="txtAmt" runat="server" style="text-align:right;" 
        MaxLength="12" onkeydown="return isNumber(event, this.id)" onkeyup="formateValue(this.id)" >
    </asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAmt" 
            ValidChars="0123456789." Enabled="True" />
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CVAmt" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Invalid value" Display="Dynamic"
        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="String" ControlToValidate="txtAmt" >
    </asp:CompareValidator>
</div>
```

### .aspx Code

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UCMask" Src="~/WebUserControl2.ascx" %>
<uc1:UCMask runat="server" DValue="" ID="txtRate" />
```

Here i need to call a `java-script function` on `onblur` event.

### Ex.:

```
<uc1:UCMask runat="server" DValue="" ID="txtRate" onCustomBlur="myFunction(this.id);"/>
```

Comment: Question is a little confusing - especially because of that _how can i create client side custom events_ part. Is your question about, how can I invoke a javascript function from aspx.cs??

Comment: I need to create custom client side events in my user control.
So that i can use this event for invocation of any `java-script`function from `.aspx` page where i used my custom control.
I think now you know what actually i need to do.

Comment: That is interesting!! But I cannot think of a scenario why you need a custom client side event. However, using @ivan.savik reply, you can invoke client script. In case, that is not what you are looking for, if you can put your scenario, may be people will get a better idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Got it. Actually, what you can do is expose a property, (OnCustomBlur, in this case) and in the user control have the setter of the property to register your client script using _ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock_

Comment: I've make a property called `callOnBlur`. And on user control's OnLoad event i added javascript function like this `txtAmt.Attributes["onblur"] = callOnBlur;`.It calls the javascript function but on next control's blur event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36449/discussion-between-ashish-rathore-and-prash)

Answer (score 0):

To "OnLoad" event of your user control you need to register startup client script where you will get the TextBox.ClientID and write your JavaScript code. Something like..

```
string javaScript = string.format("$(#'{0}').on('input', function() {alert('change occured');})", MyTextBox.ClientID);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock (this.GetType(),
    "MyClientChangeEventKey", 
     javaScript,      
      true);
```